# flashFrame: false on Electron app don't work

Tags: javascript, html, windows, electron, desktop-application

I´m trying to make my Electron app don't flash the frame when are minimized, because all times when it are minimized, it flash the frame, and some times, if I dont have focus in other program, it reopen automatically.
I just want it to stop flash the frame.

This happens all times:
[image: Flash frame on]
[image: Flash frame off]

Here is my `main.js` file:

```
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    show: false,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    flashFrame: false                        //I TRIED THIS
  })
  mainWindow.flashFrame(false)               //I TRIED THIS
  splash = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    frame: false,
    height: 600
  })
  splash.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/splash.html`);
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  var myVar = setInterval(dentroyWindows, 3000)
  function dentroyWindows() {
    splash.destroy()
    mainWindow.show()
  }

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

app.on('browser-window-created', function (e, window) {
  window.setMenu(null);
  window.flashFrame(false);                  //I TRIED THIS
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, `flashFrame` is not an option in the Electron API so it will not do anything:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  flashFrame: false
})
```

> because all times when it are minimized, it flash the frame, and some times, if I dont have focus in other program, it reopen automatically.

This is not normal behaviour. Flashing of the taskbar will only happen if `show()` or `focus()` or `restore()` are called or your app is getting focus through some other means. Without a repository that reproduces this behaviour it will be very hard for anybody to advise on a fix.

Comment: Got it. But what API must I have to make the `flashFrame`   work correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by work correctly? Calling `window.flashFrame(true)` will cause the taskbar to flash  `window.flashFrame(false)` will cause that flashing to stop. That is the only available API around taskbar flashing apart from what might happen when the app is focussed

Comment: I mean: working correctly because even setting it as false, flash continues to occur when the app is not in focus.

Comment: `window.flashFrame(false)` only stops the flashing if you've started it by calling `window.flashFrame(true)`. As I said above, the taskbar icon continually flashing is not normal behaviour but without seeing more code there is no way to know why its happening